# Creating an array based on a plot of custom function (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I'm trying to use Numpy to create a y vector that will correspond to the following plot:

[image]

The x values will run from 0 to 24, the y values should be:

0 to 6 will be 0

6 to 18 will be sort of parabola

18 to 24 will be 0 again

What is a good way to do it? I don't have any practical ideas yet (I thought about some sort of interpolation).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it assuming that you want a circle shape instead of a parabola (based on your scheme).

```
import numpy as np

length = 24
radius = 6

x = np.arange(length)
y = np.sqrt(radius**2-(x-(length/2))**2)
y = np.nan_to_num(y)

print(x)
# [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]
print(y)
# [0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.
#  0.         3.31662479 4.47213595 5.19615242 5.65685425 5.91607978
#  6.         5.91607978 5.65685425 5.19615242 4.47213595 3.31662479
#  0.         0.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
```

Comment: Not exactly the thing I had in mind but it works! :)

Comment: What did you had in mind? I am just deducing `y` points from circle mathematical equation: `(x-x_o)**2+(y-y_o)**2 = r**2`. If you prefer another shape you can just modify the equation.

Comment: Yes it is working. What I had in mind is doing something more general, like part of a sine wave that will peak at the middle and zero padding everywhere else